# sub string in unix on a character

Tags: unix

I have file names inside a directory in unix as:

```
code1_abc.txt
code2_xyz.txt
code1_pqr.txt
```

I am looping over all files in this director to do some stuff on each files:

```
for myFile in $(ls $INPUT_DIR/* | xargs -n 1 basename)
do
    echo $myFile
done
```

However, now I want to split the file name and want to get the part before the underscore i.e. `code1, code2, code3`

```
for myFile in $(ls $INPUT_DIR/* | xargs -n 1 basename)
do
    echo $myFile
    codeForCurrentFile= // want code1 here using myFile value
    echo $codeForCurrentFile // should echo code1, code2, code3 respectively
done
```

How to do this? I am using korn shell.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ksh pattern substitution to replace the underscore and anything after it with nothing (effectively delete):

```
echo ${myFile//_*/}
```

For your example:

```
codeForCurrentFile=${myFile//_*/}
```

More info here (see section 4.5.4): http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch04_05.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling out to an external program, regardless of the shell in use (provided it supports output capture of external programs, of course), such as with the following transcript:

```
pax$ fspec=code1_abc

pax$ echo $fspec
code1_abc

pax$ pre=`echo $fspec | cut -d_ -f1` ; echo $pre
code1

pax$ post=`echo $fspec | cut -d_ -f2` ; echo $post
abc
```

There are a wide variety of tools you can use to achieve this, `cut` (as above, probably the simplest), `awk`, `sed` and so on.

This has the disadvantage of kicking up external processes, something that should be okay provided you're not doing it *many* times per second. If it's something that needs to be fast, you're better off using shell-specific internal methods, such as:

```
ksh:
    fspec=code1_abc
    pre=${fspec//_*/}
    post=${fspec//*_/}
bash:
    fspec=code1_abc
    pre=${fspec%%_*}
    post=${fspec#*_}
csh:
    set fspec = code1_abc
    set arr = ( $fspec:as/_/ / )
    set pre = $arr[1]
    set post = $arr[2]
```